# No-quota push notifications for Windows Phone company app

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Is it still possible to enable authenticated (no-quota) push notifications for company app on Windows Phone?

There were a couple of blog posts by Windows Phone team documenting the process to enable no-quota push notifications for company app but now, on development portal, it is not possible to upload a certificate without linking it to an app.

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/12/10/enabling-no-quota-push-notifications-for-company-apps-on-windows-phone/
- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/06/06/no-quota-push-notifications-using-a-root-certificate-authority/

I'm sure Microsoft [added this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20570291/130929) a couple of years ago but now it seems to has been removed.

[image]

Do you know if authenticated push notifications for company app is still supported by Microsoft?

Comment: Maybe this could help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293899/authenticated-push-notifications-without-publishing-the-app-to-the-windows-phone .. one answer has an upvote

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have the old developer account UI , and I think you should upgrade to store dev :

**[Unify windows phone developer account with store developer account](https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/unify-your-windows-phone-dev-center-account-to-windows-store-dev-center/)**

However , there was old trick for enterprise testers to test their apps by passing windows store with **[Build it Beta](https://dzone.com/articles/bypass-windows-phone-store)**, it is similar to testflight, or hockeyapps.

**Update:**

if you are saying that you have updated your account, and you got the new dashboard simply follow :

Dashboard>apps>services>push notifications

as appears in image below

[image]

Comment: We are definitely on the new UI. We would like to enable Push notification for enterprise app without any trick.

Comment: @systempuntoout sure you can do it without any tricks, I thought you lost your enterprise account :).

Comment: The push notification settings in your screenshot are linked to a "published" app. Microsoft, a couple of years ago added a feature to upload a certificate without publishing any app at all.

Comment: @systempuntoout it is true that app is published , but the certificate option is available even without publishing, certificates are needed for Authenticated push notifications , check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx

Comment: Do you suggest to upload the enterprise app without publishing it as a beta? That looks like a trick to me. I'm using authenticated push notification for another public app available on the store; this app I'm talking about, should be kept private and still supports authenticated push notifications.

Comment: @systempuntoout authenticated push notifications doesn't necessarily require publishing.

Comment: @systempuntoout check this AWS solution http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-mpns.html

Comment: I do not want to use private beta (Betas expire) and I do not want to upload my enterprise app to the store (it requires review by Microsoft and we can't give them our enterprise data).